# Update null value on existing column/tables using aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql

- I have updated an existing table with a column called "Expected Profit".
- All the existing records created before now have this field with a `null` value.
- I want to write SQL statement to update that  `null` value using some combination of some of the values already in that table.

The formula would be something like this ( all those are values existing in the table ) :

```
Expected Profit = quantity * (1 - failure_rate) * expected_sales_price - (product_fixed_cost + young_product_cost_value)
```

Now I want to update it with SQL statement, but I dont really know how to do it :

```
UPDATE tablePlannedSales
SET expected_profit = (*SQL I should use to set the formula above*)
WHERE expected_profit IS NULL
```

Any help would be very welcome,

Comment: Sounds good Just do it! Use `WHERE expected_profit IS NULL and ID = 'test value'` to update one line first to be sure of your calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case all columns that you need within your formula are part of the table you want to update, it's not required do a select. You can just execute the update command according to your example:

```
UPDATE tablePlannedSales 
  SET expected_profit = quantity * (1 - failure_rate) * expected_sales_price - (product_fixed_cost + young_product_cost_value) 
WHERE expected_profit IS NULL
```

If this does not work as expected, something with your formula is wrong or some columns within the formula are not present in this table.

Comment: Thanks , this is what I wanted to know. I was wondering if there is any special command to get those values or if I could just write the raw formula .